# onCameraFrame seems not to work

Tags: android, opencv

I try to draw a list as buttons.
However, my app doesn't have any action when I press any of them.

Here is my code:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final int viewMode = mViewMode;
    Log.i("test", "onCameraFrame");
    switch (viewMode) {
    case VIEW_MODE_GRAY:
        title.setText("J");
        break;
    case VIEW_MODE_RGBA:
        break;
}
   return mRgba;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item == mItemMode1) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_1;
        } else if (item == mItemMode2) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_2;
        } else if (item == mItemMode3) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_3;
        } else if (item == mItemModeRTDemo) {
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_RTDemo;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Actually,I deleted `private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;`.Before I deleted the CamaraBridgeViewBase, my list worked properly.I don't know whether the problem has something to do with my action.

Down is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any"
    android:id="@+id/tutorial2_activity_surface_view" />

 <org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
     android:text="title"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`onCameraFrame()` should return a `Mat`, but your code doesn't.

You need something like

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final int viewMode = mViewMode;
    Log.i("test", "onCameraFrame");
    switch (viewMode)
    {
    case VIEW_MODE_GRAY:
        title.setText("J");
        return inputFrame.gray();
    case VIEW_MODE_RGBA:
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written return argument, but it is at the end. After all the case (I have 4 cases, but the other 2 has no actions now)is over.
Is there any different to put return in all the cases and after all the cases?